# 考えないことには　と　考えないとなれば　（新完全マスタ　N2）

Tags: grammar, jlpt

> 1.「何か対策を考えないことには国民の不安は消えないだろう。」
>
> 2.「何か対策を考えないとなれば国民の不安は消えないだろ。」

どうして2番目の文は間違いですか？

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does ～ないことには and ～なければ differ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40563/how-does-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af-and-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%aa%e3%81%91%e3%82%8c%e3%81%b0-differ)

Comment: ^ But that thread is not dealing with the construction 「[Sentence]+となれば」, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

文法的には一応どちらもアリかと思いますが、ニュアンスがかなり違います。
文脈を考えれば１のほうが自然です。

１では「対策を考えないと国民の不安は消えない、ゆえに対策を考える必要がある」
２では「対策を考えない。ゆえに国民の不安も消えない」

と、述べている因果関係は同じでも、「実際に対策を考えるかどうか」の前提が違います。
１では対策の考察を促しているのに対し、２では対策を諦めているように聞こえます。
国民の不安が消えないことを受け入れるのはさすがに不自然ということで、
１が正解となっているのではないでしょうか。

あと、最初の「何か…」も２の場合はやや不自然です。
対策を考えないことを前提として仮定している場合は、
具体的な対策を求める「何か」は必要ありません。
なのでやはり、ほぼ決まっている前提の結果を紹介する「となれば」より、
避けるべき結果を紹介する「ことには」のほうがしっくりきます。

Answer (score 3):

「対策を考えない**となれば**」には、「何か」ではなく「何も」を使うと思います。
（２．「何**か**対策を考えないとなれば～～」→「何**も**対策を考えないとなれば～～」）
「『何も対策を考えない』となれば…」というふうに、「と」は引用を示していて、
打消しの「考えない」には「何か」ではなく「何も」を使うからです。
（×「何**か**考えない。」→「何**も**考えない。」）